# Exec a function when (re)connected to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm using `https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver`

Is there any chance to be notified when Go MongoDB client is connected or reconnected? I wish to log this event, but don't see a way, so currently reconnecting happens on the background and is invisible.

---

Trying according to the advice in a comment:

```
type wConn struct {
    net.Conn
}

func (c *wConn) Close() error {
    fmt.Println("closed")
    return c.Conn.Close()
}

type wDialer struct {
    net.Dialer
}

func NewDialer() *wDialer {
    dialer := &wDialer{}
    dialer.Timeout = 5 * time.Second

    return dialer
}

func (d *wDialer) DialContext(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
    c, err := ... // ??? How to get a connection?
    // Like this?
    // nd := &net.Dialer{}
    // c, err := nd.DialContext(ctx, network, address)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    nc := &wConn{Conn: c}
    return nc, nil
}

...

td := NewDialer()
client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017").SetDialer(td))
```

Here the question near `???` is what is a way to get a `Conn` connection object?

Comment: Set a dialer using [ClientOptions.Dialer](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ClientOptions.Dialer) and wrap returned connection with Close method hook.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, any example? I'm not really sure how to implement such trick

Comment: I don't know of an example.  Here are more details on the approach. Perhaps somebody else will be motivated to write out all of the code for a proper answer. 1) Implement the [ContextDialer](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ContextDialer) interface using a [net.Dialer](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer).  2) Wrap returned conn with `type wConn { net.Conn }` with method `func (c wConn) Close() error { return c.Conn.Close() }`.  With this, app knows when conn is dialed and closed.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, I'm trying to code your advice, appended example to the question. At the `???` - how to get a `Conn` object?

Comment: Call DialContext on a net.Dialer.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, added commented out code below `???`. You mean like that? But isn't it awkward to create another one `net.Dialer` if my object `wDialer` already contains it? Maybe there is a way to call already "embedded" functions?

Comment: Could you elaborate what’s s the purpose of logging this event in your use case?

Comment: @WanBachtiar, reconnecting means interruptions somewhere, I wish to know about them. Is it OK for you to stay blind when your DB disappears?

Comment: The reason I asked is because MongoDB drivers connects to a server for a command. i.e. find, update, ping, etc. Also, MongoDB itself being a distributed database, the drivers have provided resiliency way of reconnecting to primary/secondary nodes seamlessly. Generally, if you would like to know more about the DB uptime/reliability, you would add monitoring on the DB, and not coupled together into an application.